# can sprite group in pygame contain subgroups containing sprites apart from the normal sprites ?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and I was wondering if the following was possible.

Say I have 2 Spritegroups called Sprites and Sprites1 each having a set of different non overlapping sprites in them. Is it possible to do something like Sprites.add(Sprites1) ?

Comment: Without meaning to seem unhelpful, whenever I see a question beginning "is it possible..?" my reply would be "have you tried it?". If you have tried it and you get an error, then that makes for a far more specific question. Personally, I think experimenting and seeing what does and doesn't work is a great way to learn something new. Good luck, and have fun.

Comment: Suggestion: avoid naming your groups like `Sprites` or `Sprites1`. Uppercasing first letter should be reserved for *class* names, not their *instances*. As in `enemies = pygame.sprites.Group()`, `boss = pygame.sprites.Sprite()`, `enemies.add(boss)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check the pygame documentation 
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group

```
pygame.sprite.Group.add(*sprite)
```

- any number of sprites

Hope that helped :)
Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Alex answer is correct, but it relies on 2 subtle tricks that you may not be aware of, and are worth explaining:

- **Sprite groups are *iterable*:** if you have a group named `enemies`, you can easily loop over all sprites that it contains:

  `for enemy in enemies:
      enemy.health *= 2`

Pretty convenient, huh? Just don't be tempted to use slices and indexes: a group is *not* a list! For that, use `group.sprites()`, which *returns* a list (but is still a *method*, hence the mandatory parenthesis).

- **`Group.add()` method takes multiple arguments**, each one a sprite. So you can add multiple sprites in a single `add`, like:

  `world.add(boss, ninja, tree, player)`

That is cool, but it gets better: if you have a sequence (list, tuple, etc) of sprites or an iterator/generator that yields sprites you can use the `*` syntax to expand the elements into multiple arguments. Also pretty convenient, isn't it? :)

Both features can be combined (they were designed to be), which results in the awesome syntax Alex used:

```
world.add(*enemies)
```

Good luck killing them all :)